# Крестики нолики на c#

Tags: c#

Как сделать, чтобы программа не ставила нолики в те поля, которые уже заполнены ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string name;
        bool pc = false;
        int hod = 1;
        bool turn = true; //true = x turn, false=y turn
        int turn_count = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void check()
        {

            {

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int p = rnd.Next(0, 8);
                if ((pc == true) || (name != A1.Text) || (name != A2.Text) || (name != A3.Text)
                   || (name != B1.Text) || (name != B2.Text) || (name != B3.Text) || (name != C1.Text)
                   || (name != C2.Text) || (name != C3.Text))
                {
                    switch (p)
                    {
                        case 0: A1.Text = "O";
                            A1.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 1: A2.Text = "O";
                            A2.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 2: A3.Text = "O";
                            A3.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 3: B1.Text = "O";
                            B1.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 4: B2.Text = "O";
                            B2.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 5: B3.Text = "O";
                            B3.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 6: C1.Text = "O";
                            C1.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 7: C2.Text = "O";
                            C2.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                        case 8: C3.Text = "O";
                            C3.Enabled = false;
                            turn_count++;
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }



        private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (turn)
                b.Text = "X";
           if (!turn)
                b.Text = "O";
            pc = true;
            name = (sender as Button).Name;
            label1.Text = name+label1.Text;
            b.Enabled = false;
            turn_count++;
            label1.Text = turn_count.ToString();
            checkwinner();
            check();

        }
        private void checkwinner()
        {
            bool it_is_win = false;
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))

                    it_is_win = true;

                if ((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && (!B1.Enabled))

                    it_is_win = true;

                if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))

                    it_is_win = true;


                  if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))

                    it_is_win = true;

                else if ((A2.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C2.Text) && (!A2.Enabled))

                    it_is_win = true;

                else  if ((A3.Text == B3.Text) && (B3.Text == C3.Text) && (!A3.Enabled))

                      it_is_win = true;


                  else if ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))

                      it_is_win = true;

                  else if ((A3.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C1.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))

                      it_is_win = true;

                if (it_is_win)
                {
                    disableButton();
                    String winner = "";
                    if (turn)
                        winner = "X";
                   if(!turn)
                        winner = "O";

                    MessageBox.Show(winner + " wins");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (turn_count == 9)
                        MessageBox.Show("Draw");
                }
            }
        }
        private void disableButton()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = false;

                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void новаяИграToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            turn = true;
            turn_count = 0;

            try
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = true;
                    b.Text = "";

                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Есть вот такой код. Думал добавлять в переменную имена нажатых кнопок и сравнивать с названием кнопки, куда компьютер поместил нолик, но что-то не ахти выходит.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то вам просто нужно перед тем как ставить нолики, сначала проверять нет ли там чего другого (ифом простым).
а если долго, то возможно более понятным и правильным способом решения этой задачи была бы реализация на двумерном инт-масиве с размерами как у полей в вашей игре (самый простой вариант 3х3, например).
то-есть при старте игры мы устанавливаем все значения в масиве в какое-нибудь число, например 5 (это будет значить что никто еще не делал ход и 5 - значит пустая клетка)

```
|5|5|5|
|5|5|5|
|5|5|5|
```

потом предположим компьютер делает первый ход - обозначем его цифрой 1 (это как крестик).

```
|5|5|5|
|5|1|5|
|5|5|5|
```

игрок ему отвечает и ставит где-то 0 (нужно проверить сначала что в этой клетке стоит 5 (то-есть она пуста) ):

```
|5|5|5|
|5|1|5|
|5|5|0|
```

и так далее..
после каждого хода мы запускаем функцию, которая проверяет не победил ли походивший игрок (нет ли по вертикали, горизонтали, диагонали ряда 1 или 0).
и задача отрисовки будет просто сводиться к кейс-свичу вида:

```
если 0: нарисовать 0, 
если 1: нарисовать +, 
5: ниче не рисовать
```

Такое отделение логики игры от ее отрисовки сделает написание игры в разы проще и понятнее, и запутаться здесь практически негде.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Действительно, довольно просто в реализации.

Comment: Можете помочь? Что-то не выходит у меня по вашему методу.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button b = (Button)sender;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Text))
    return;

  ...
}
```